# Which caching will be faster, data as files in folders and sub folders or data as database content?

Tags: database, performance, server, directory, response

After getting answer from @Andrew Regan, I have edited my question and its explanation.

I want to serve html data to millions. And I came to know - its done by caching.

I knew HTML as files and now I have also read that HTML pages are stored in databases to serve.

Thus my question is, which of the following caching will be quicker
- Caching of HTML files in different folders and sub folders
 or
- Caching of HTML data in database.

Even if this experiment is done on only single file / table record, which method would be faster? (No doubt the result for single file or record will be out in nano seconds, yet, which caching will happen faster? e.g. either one procedure would take 0.000000001 second and another procedure would take 0.000000002 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us anything about your application's architecture, or your expected traffic, or whether you've considered existing frameworks for solving your problem. So this will be a very high-level view.

The answer is **caches**.

With static content you shouldn't *need* to expose the end user to the performance of either the filesystem or the database. You shouldn't want to anyway.

If you're simply serving up fixed, unchanging, static content, on a single server, the most effective option is to simply read the whole lot into a cache (ideally held in RAM, not disk) on startup and proceed from there without any additional loads or fetches. (Even better, you'd use a [proven cache outside of your network](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn/).)

That should be **extremely** fast for the end-user. As far as performance on the machine is concerned, it shouldn't make a big difference how you *seed* the cache, whether from the filesystem or the database, though disk is perhaps easier to work with.

You can load data lazily into the cache if you prefer, or if you have changing content. It still won't really matter if you load it from disk or from a DB provided you cache aggressively enough. Set as long a TTL (lifetime) as you can to avoid unnecessary reloads.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. After you answered I edited my question to explain my exact question. Thank you once again.

Comment: You haven't given enough detail about your environment, your filesystem, your DB, your usage, or your particular needs to allow a sensible answer. There are too many variables. Best practice is not to serve content (especially static content) from *any* of your physical hardware.

Comment: In the overflow of developers you are the guy responding to this question. Thanks for that. Now can i know what exactly you mean by environment, ...? Shall i take it that, you are asking (environment = windows / linux), (filesystem = ntfs / EXT4), (DB = mysql / sql / oracle)?So that articulate my question again.

Comment: your answer has helped me to understand what exactly I was seeking. I am editing my question.